# c# Sockets messages between client and server

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server

I'm currently learning how to use sockets on c#, and have a question regarding how the messages should be between the client and the server.

Currently i have a server application and a client application, and in each application i have some strings that are the commands. When, for example, the client needs the time from the server, i have a string like this:

`public const string GET_TIME_COMMAND = "<GET_TIME_COMMAND>";`

Then i have a if statement on the server, thats checks if the message sent from the client starts with that string and if so, it sends another message to the client with another command and with the time in a json string.

My question is, is this a good way to do it, and if not could you advise me on another way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TCP

Keep in mind that TCP is a stream based connection. You may or may not get the complete command in one message. You may even get multiple commands in one read.

To solve this TCP messages usually have a unique start and stop sequence or byte that may not be part of the message.

```
(SomeCommand)
```

Where `(` is the start and `)` is the stop symbol.

An alternative way os to prepend a header to the actual message that contains the message length.

```
11 S O M E M E S S A G E
```

Where 11 is the message length and `somemessage` is the actual message. You'd usually transmit the length as a byte or ushort, not a string literal.

In both cases you have to read over and over until you have one complete message - then you can dispatch it into the application.

Also TCP is connection based. You have to connect to the remote site. The advantage is that TCP makes sure that all messages are sent in the very order you put them in. TCP will also automatically re-send lost packets and you don't have to worry about that.

## UDP

In contrast to that UDP is a message/packet based, but it is not reliable. You may or may not get the message and have to re-send it in some cases. Also UDP doesn't have a notion of a "session". You would have to do that yourself if required.

The answer to your question depends on the protocol used. For TCP this won't work well with your current message format. You'd probably have to prepend a header.

You could use UDP, but then you may have to detect and re-send messages that got lost.